# Is there a Java Google App Engine Datastore equivalent of Oracle Sequence?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

For a java based google app engine web application, is there some sort of equivalent way to get a sequential value similar to an oracle sequence?

Suppose I have a servlet, lets call it `SequenceServlet` with a very simple job. It will simply write the next value in the sequence.

Using Oracle you could create a sequence - lets call it "my_seq" and execute this SQL:

```
select my_seq.nextval from dual
```

Although there might be many application servers, there is one centralized DB so this is easy. But my google app engine app uses a HRD (High Replication Datastore). How can I ensure that each application server will respond with the next number in the sequence?

I want to ensure that after startup if you have 2 client requests... say request A got sequence number 10 and request B got sequence number 15.

I want to ensure that the following is true:

- Request B for sure happened AFTER request A
- There are exactly 4 requests that happened between requests A and B

And this would need to be true in general for any 2 sequence numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the HRD this isn't as trivial as one might hope it to be.  There's a reasonable article at the following URL (with Java examples) that details how to implement sharded counters which seems to be essentially what you want.

[Sharding Counters](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters)

Through the use of datastore transactions you can ensure a counter value atomically increases.  By sharding the counter you can ensure that performance of those transactions scales to your needs.

Additionally by making use of memcache it's possible to improve performance of reads.